# Why does "vue-cli-service build" create multiple versions of a file instead of putting it into the app-chunk

Tags: vue.js, webpack, deployment, vue-cli

i´ve setup a VUE-project with pretty much the default configuration, that vue-cli "vue create myapp" gave me.

So the vue.config.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
      publicPath: "/myapp",
      outputDir: "../dist",
      devServer: {
        host: "localhost"
      },
      configureWebpack: {
        devtool: 'source-map'
      }
    };
```

and the webpack.config.js has this content:

```
module.exports = {
   devTool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
}
```

When i run "npm run build", which invokes a "vue-cli-service build", in the ../dist/js - Folder, i´ll find multiple versions of my login-Page:

```
..\dist\js\app.794a7e13.js
..\dist\js\app.794a7e13.js.map
..\dist\js\chunk-2d216214.4700c1d8.js
..\dist\js\chunk-2d216214.4700c1d8.js.map
..\dist\js\chunk-2d216257.256ee085.js
..\dist\js\chunk-2d216257.256ee085.js.map
..\dist\js\chunk-27e4b2e6.df5ff56f.js
..\dist\js\chunk-27e4b2e6.df5ff56f.js.map
..\dist\js\chunk-vendors.857de610.js
..\dist\js\chunk-vendors.857de610.js.map
..\dist\js\login3.88e7e7b7.js
..\dist\js\login3.88e7e7b7.js.map
..\dist\js\login8.736ad963.js
..\dist\js\login8.736ad963.js.map
..\dist\js\login9.80755e47.js
..\dist\js\login9.80755e47.js.map
..\dist\js\login16.e1a7a747.js
..\dist\js\login16.e1a7a747.js.map
..\dist\js\login17.4bf5365c.js
..\dist\js\login17.4bf5365c.js.map
..\dist\js\login32.ffe5b74f.js
..\dist\js\login32.ffe5b74f.js.map
..\dist\js\login33.0c9bb904.js
..\dist\js\login33.0c9bb904.js.map
..\dist\js\login34.9263f648.js
..\dist\js\login34.9263f648.js.map
..\dist\js\login35.0d1ff538.js
..\dist\js\login35.0d1ff538.js.map
..\dist\js\login36.65fdd2d1.js
... (several more to come)
```

In the css-folder, it´s the same: nearly a dozen loginXXXXXX.css - files there.

Does anyone has an idea, why this happens?
Or any hint, how to prevent this?

Ideal would be a configuration, where "login" will be part of "app" ...

And as we are here, a second questions:  how can i configure human-readable/debuggable code even in production builds?

Thank you for any tipps!